# Change font color Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, text, colors

I have this line of code working:

```
PrintText += "<font color='#33B5E5'>P1</font>";
```

This line prints P1 in skyblue, but P1 can chanche depending on the lenguage selected on the app so I want to take the text from Strings.xml

In Strings.xml I have:

```
<string name="str_P1">P1</string>
```

I tried this:

```
PrintText += "<font color='#33B5E5'>getResources().getString(R.string.str_P1)</font>";
```

This line prints "getResources().getString(R.string.str_P1)" in skyblue not "P1"

Also tried this:
Strings.xml:

```
<string name="str_P1">"<font color='#33B5E5'>P1</font>"</string>
```

Code:

```
PrintText += getResources().getString(R.string.str_P1);
```

This line prints "P1" in black, not in skyblue as desired.

What do I have to do to print "P1" in skyblue taking P1 from Strings.xml?

Comment: because `getResources().getString(R.string.str_P1)` is considered as a String in your code. End the string quote (") before and start after the `getResources()` line

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintText += "<font color='#33B5E5'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.str_P1) + "</font>";
```